# Why is my refrigerator leaking?

Tags: leak, refrigerator

The make of the unit is GE and below is a link to a picture of the label on the back. There aren't any other markings anywhere. I'm guessing this is an older model.

[image: Label on back of fridge]

Here's a close-up of the ceiling of the refrigerator where the water seems to be leaking from.

[image: Ceiling of fridge]

I've read that the possible cause may be a clogged drain hole (with ice) and that leaving the unit unplugged for about four hours may do the trick. So I've unplugged it for now and am waiting. Thought I'd upload these pictures here to see if anyone can help further diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [GE knowledgebase](http://www.geappliances.com/search/google/infobase/10001430.htm)

> **Refrigerator - Icemaker Leaking or Dripping Water**
>
> If your icemaker is leaking water into your ice bucket or onto your
> floor, several things could be the source of the problem. Check the
> following items:
>
> - Be sure the water line fittings are secure.
> - Check the water valve for leaks.
> - See if water is leaking from the fill tube extension.
> - See if the defrost water drain is cracked or overflowing.
> - Check for water on the exterior of the refrigerator case.
> - See if the refrigerator is leveled. [How to Level a Refrigerator](http://www.geappliances.com/search/google/infobase/10000323.htm).
>
> Note: If the icemaker is leaking water onto the floor of your home,
> turn off the water supply to your icemaker. This line is usually
> located under the kitchen sink. Locate the cold water line under the
> sink, and look for a small 1/4" copper line attached to it. Where
> these two lines meet, there will be a saddle valve. Sticking out from
> this valve will be a post with a wire running through it. This is the
> shut-off valve. Turn this valve in a clockwise manner until it stops.
> This will shut off the water to the icemaker. If the water line is not
> connected under the sink, it will be in the basement or crawl space.

I would check items 4 & 6.

For a clogged defrost drain [GE](http://www.geappliances.com/search/google/infobase/10000306.htm) says

> **Top freezer refrigerators:**
>
> Water under the vegetable pans is the usual evidence of a clogged
> defrost drain tube. Most top freezer models require some disassembly
> to access the defrost drain tube. We recommend that you contact
> service. If you would like to schedule a service appointment, please
> contact GE Consumer Service at 1-800-432-2737 or [schedule a service
> appointment
> on-line.](http://www.geappliances.com/service_and_support/service/)

Which isn't much help if you want to fix it yourself.

Here is an image of the cabinet assembly

[image]

And the unit parts (notice the drain tube is circled).

[image]

Images from [Appliance Parts Pros.com](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/partsearch/model.aspx?model_id=226535&diagram_id=20244826#d20244826)

**WARNING:** If you are going to take the thing apart, make sure you **unplug** it first.